# Error when using Spring Security 5 and Auth0

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2, auth0

I am configuring my Spring Boot application using auth0. For that I am using the following tutorial: https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/backend/java-spring-security5

But I am getting the following error:"

```
class com.nimbusds.jose.Algorithm cannot be cast to class com.nimbusds.jose.JWSAlgorithm (com.nimbusds.jose.Algorithm and com.nimbusds.jose.JWSAlgorithm are in unnamed module of loader 'app')
```

I am using Spring Boot 2.5.0-M2, and Kotlin (just in case it matters)

Comment: did you find a solution? We got the same error for 2.5.0-RC1

Comment: I tried with a previous version, and it worked

Answer (score 0):

It is a [bug](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/9651) in 5.5.0 pre releases of spring security which is used by spring boot 2.5.0.

There is a [PR to fix this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/pull/9658) that hopefully will be released soon.

Until then you can create the `JwTDecoder` as a workaround:

```
@Bean 
JwtDecoder jwtDecoder() {
    String issuerUri = ...;
    String jwkSetUri = ...;
    OAuth2TokenValidator<Jwt> validator = JwtValidators.createDefaultWithIssuer(issuerUri);
    NimbusJwtDecoder jwtDecoder = NimbusJwtDecoder.withJwtSetUri(jwkSetUri).build();
    jwtDecoder.setJwtValidator(validator);
    return jwtDecoder;
}
```